# Freemarker website throws error with IE10

Tags: java, freemarker, internet-explorer-10

When I open [this website](http://alionu.skillport.com/skillportfe/login.action) on IE10 desktop, it shows the Freemarker error stack.

```
Error: on line 18, column 32 in WEB-INF/ftl/common/requestVariables.ftl
Expecting a number here, found: .
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> browserMinor=applicationBean.browser.browserMinor?number [on line 18, column 17 in WEB-INF/ftl/common/requestVariables.ftl]
 in include "/WEB-INF/ftl/common/requestVariables.ftl" [on line 12, column 1 in WEB-INF/ftl/login/login.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.NonNumericalException: Error: on line 18, column 32 in WEB-INF/ftl/common/requestVariables.ftl
Expecting a number here, found: .
    at freemarker.core.StringBuiltins$numberBI.calculateResult(StringBuiltins.java:186)
    at freemarker.core.StringBuiltins$StringBuiltIn._getAsTemplateModel(StringBuiltins.java:71)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:90)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
    at freemarker.core.AssignmentInstruction.accept(AssignmentInstruction.java:86)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
```

If I change the connection-string `(F12 developer tools, press Tools > Change user-agen string > Mozilla Firefox)`, it works well.

Is it due to the browser-sniffing in the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the Web application framework (not FreeMarker) sets browserMinor to `""` for IE10, which is of course not a number. Either it should put "0" here, or requestVariables.ftl has to be modified to handle this case.